# Error using WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS

Tags: perl, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs, www-mechanize

I've just started to use PhantomJS for webscraping. I installed the module and imported the package in Perl. But I get an error when I try to 'new' the module.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new();
```

I get the following error :

`Couldn't launch [phantomjs /Library/Perl/5.16/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS/ghostdriver/main.js --port=8910 --logLevel=OFF]: No such file or directory / 0 at /Library/Perl/5.16/WWW/Mechanize/PhantomJS.pm line 177.`

I'm sure that I'm able to import the package. I was looking through cpan website for answers and was wondering if I need to give any launch arguments in the new function?

Thanks

Comment: It says it can't execute `phantomjs`. Have you installed phantomjs (the program, not the CPAN module)?

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/download.html